# Performing a custom action when a given mocked void method is called (EasyMock)

Tags: java, spring, mockito, easymock

I would like to be able to perform a custom action when a given void method is called.

For example:-

```
private IMocksControl control;
private Map<String, Double> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
private Abc abc;

public void setup(){
  control = EasyMock.createControl();
  abc = control.createMock(Abc.class);
}
```

Suppose there is a void method in class Abc which i want to use. But when that method is called I want to put an entry inside the dataMap hashmap.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: This is easymock 1.x. Are you really using this?

Comment: Yes! We are using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully remember the code for EasyMock 1 (which is obsolete for more than 10 years now) but there should be a `control.andAnswer()` where you will be able to do something like:

```
abc.method();
control.andAnswer(new IAnswer() {
    dataMap.put(...);
});
```